# How do I block the child threads while the parent thread waits for a user input?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a parent thread which creates child threads A,B,C,D,E,F. Each of these child threads runs a different disk scheduling algorithm and prints the result simultaneously. The task is to block these child threads while the parent thread waits for the user to input a file name, from which the disk scheduling data is parsed and read in order to be used in the disk scheduling algorithms for the child threads.

Currently my program first takes the user input before the creation of the child threads and therefor there is no need to block however my task is to block them.

```
#define N 71

typedef struct 
{
    int totalCylinders;
    int cylindersInReqQueue;
    int currentPos;
    int prevDiskRequest;
    int *requestQueueArr;
    char id;
    char *filename;
} disk_data;

sem_t semaphore;
pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void *runner(void *args);
void runscheduler(char name, disk_data data);

void *runner(void *args)
{
        disk_data data = *(disk_data*)args;
        char threadName = data.id;
        
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        
        while(strlen(data.filename) == 0)
        {
           printf("IT REACHED THIS> GOING OUT");
           pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &mutex);
        }
        
        printf("Hello from thread %u I am %c\n", (int)pthread_self(),threadName);
        runscheduler(threadName,data);
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
        
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void runscheduler(char name, disk_data data)
{
   switch(name) 
   {
      case 'A' :
         firstComeFirstServe(data.cylindersInReqQueue, data.currentPos, data.requestQueueArr);
         break;
      case 'B' :
         shortestSeekTimeFirst(data.totalCylinders, data.cylindersInReqQueue, data.currentPos, data.requestQueueArr);
         break;
      case 'C' :
         scan(data.totalCylinders, data.currentPos, data.prevDiskRequest, data.cylindersInReqQueue, data.requestQueueArr);
         break;
      case 'D' :
         cScan(data.totalCylinders, data.currentPos, data.prevDiskRequest, data.cylindersInReqQueue, data.requestQueueArr);
         break;
      case 'E' :
         look(data.totalCylinders,data.currentPos,data.prevDiskRequest,data.cylindersInReqQueue,data.requestQueueArr);
         break;
      case 'F' :   
         cLook(data.totalCylinders,data.currentPos,data.prevDiskRequest,data.cylindersInReqQueue,data.requestQueueArr);
         break;
      default :
         printf("Invalid grade\n" );
   }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
   disk_data dd;
   pthread_t tid[N];
   int* res;
   char *input;
   int i,ret;
   dd.cylindersInReqQueue =0;
   dd.requestQueueArr = (int *) malloc(dd.cylindersInReqQueue * sizeof(int));   
   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
   printf("***Disk Scheduler Simulation***");
   input = readAndParse(&dd.totalCylinders, &dd.cylindersInReqQueue, &dd.currentPos, &dd.prevDiskRequest, &dd.requestQueueArr);
   dd.filename = input;
   for(i = 65; i < N; i++) 
   {
      dd.id = (char)i;
      ret =  pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, &runner, &dd);
      if(ret != 0) 
      {
         perror("Error: pthread_create() failed\n");
      }
      sleep(1);
  
      printf ("Thread %c is created\n", i);
   }
   
   
   for(i = 65; i < N; i++) 
   {
      if (pthread_join(tid[i], (void **) &res) != 0) 
      {
         perror("Failed to join thread");
      }
      printf ("Thread %c has terminated\n", i);
   }
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
   printf ("All threads are now finished\n");
   
   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re "*Currently my program first takes the user input before the creation of the child threads and therefor there is no need to block however my task is to block them.*", And what's the problem with that?

Comment: This is for an assignment and it specifically asks to first have a parent thread which creates these child threads and have each child thread carry out a disk scheduling algorithm. And then to block the child threads while the parent thread waits for user input. I didnt use any blocking for the threads, the threads are just created after the input is taken from user. And I'm new to threads, I am not sure how to block the child threads while having the parent thread wait for the input.

Comment: Implement message queue(s). Make each thread wait for message (possibly containing the user input, if the thread needs that, possibly just message without actual data, which means the thread should stop waiting and do something). Google: pthread message queue example

Comment: Re "*block the child threads while the parent thread waits for user input.*", So you want the parent to pause the threads while they're in the middle of doing their "disk scheduling algorithm"? Are the threads able to periodically call a function? Do you want the parent to wait for the threads to become paused? Or did you actually mean you want to only start the disk scheduling algorithm after the parent has obtained user input?

Comment: @ikegami "(10 marks). The parent thread creates six child threads, i.e., thread A, B, C, D, E,
and F that respectively runs the FCFS, SSTF program, SCAN, C-SCAN, LOOK, and
C-LOOK disk schedulers. Threads A, B, C, D, E, and F block while waiting for input
from the parent thread. " This is what it asks even I am confused as to what they want us to do but from what I understand I think its to make the child threads wait till the user inputs something.

Comment: For a new user here, one advise: Format your code consistently. Not only will people here be able to read and understand it easier, the same applies to you as well. Many IDEs have autoformatting features built into them. Also, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, just FYI, threads don't have much of a parent-child relation, so you can freely switch the code either part runs without any further implication.

Comment: You keep cutting the requirements short, giving us no way to interpret the same sentence you keep repeating. If the threads are supposed to wait *until* input has been obtained, and if input is only obtained once, it's just a simple semaphore. Or a simple "input obtained" flag protected by a mutex, and a cond var to notify when the flag is changed.

Comment: No there can be more than one input. so after its done displaying the results for the first input, it asked for another input and it will keep on doing so until user inputs QUIT.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72084569/758133, and the other 'six child threads' questions posted in the last week, (one, at least, was deleted when answered).